# Eventbrite Redirect URI iOS OAuthSwift

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, eventbrite

I am trying to figure out how to do OAuth within Swift. In particular I am trying to authenticate with OAuth 2 and Eventbrite. I believe I have everything set up accordingly on my end:

```
func doOAuthEventbrite(){
    let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    Eventbrite["consumerKey"]!,
        consumerSecret: Eventbrite["consumerSecret"]!,
        authorizeUrl:   "https://www.eventbrite.com/oauth/authorize",
        responseType:   "token"
    )
    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "eventbriteanalytics://oauth-callback/eventbrite")!, scope: "", state: "", success: {
        credential, response in
        println(credential.oauth_token)
        }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
            println(error.localizedDescription)
    })
}
```

However when I go to the Eventbrite OAuth page (after I accept that I want to connect with this application with my account) I am met with a 'Oops something went wrong!' error.  The URL is the following:

https://www.eventbrite.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=REAL_API_ID_HERE&redirect_uri=eventbriteanalytics://oauth-callback/eventbrite&response_type=token

My expected behavior is that the redirect_uri goes back to the app.  However it just stays within Safari.

As a sanity check, I was able to run an OAuth against an Instagram app and everything worked fine (received access code) and was forwarded back to the app itself (so no problem with my URL Scheme being incorrect).

Reviewing the Eventbrite documentation, they provided the following guidance for the redirect_uri:

'This value, configurable per API Key, should contain a web address that the user will be redirected to after they approve or deny authorization for your app. For mobile clients, development, or testing purposes, you may want to set this value to http://localhost/.'

My question is how am I able to redirect the User back to the app once they authenticate if my URL Scheme isn't valid so I can retrieve the access code and thus get the access token?

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

> As a sanity check, I was able to run an OAuth against an Instagram app and everything worked fine (received access code) and was forwarded back to the app itself (so no problem with my URL Scheme being incorrect).

You may be one of the few people that has got to work in Swift. Do you have the code example so we can review what you did and maybe help with an answer to the question?

Thanks